# Passing parameters through factory-boy Factory to SubFactory without specifying it

Tags: python, pytest, factory-boy

I'm using the pythons factory_boy package to create instances of models for testing purposes.

I want to pass the parameters used when calling Facotry.create() to all the SubFactories in the Factory being called.

**Here's how I do it now:**

Example 1:
I have to explicitly set the `company` when calling the SubFactory (the `BagFactory`)

```
class BagTrackerFactory(BaseFactory):
    company = factory.SubFactory(CompanyFactory)
    bag = factory.SubFactory(BagFactory, company=factory.SelfAttribute("..company"))


class BagFactory(BaseFactory):
    company = factory.SubFactory(CompanyFactory)
```

Example 2:
In this example, I have to add `company` to `Params` in the `BagFactory`, so I can pass it down to `ItemFactory` which has the `company` parameter.

```
class BagTrackerFactory(BaseFactory):
    company = factory.SubFactory(CompanyFactory)
    bag = factory.SubFactory(BagFactory, company=factory.SelfAttribute("..company"))


class BagFactory(BaseFactory):
    item = factory.SubFactory(ItemFactory, company=factory.SelfAttribute("..company"))

    class Params:
        company = factory.SubFactory(CompanyFactory)


class ItemFactory(BaseFactory):
    company = factory.SubFactory(CompanyFactory)
```

The reason why I do it like this is that it saves time and it makes sense that the `Bag` belongs to the same `company` as the `BagTracker` when created by the same Factory.

*Note: the `BaseFactory` is `factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory`*

**Question:**

What I would like is to have `company` (and all the other parameters) from the parent Factory be passed down to SubFactories without having to pass it explicitly. And this continues downstream all the way to the last SubFactory, so every model has the same `company`, from the topmost parent Factory to the lowest child SubFactory. I hope you understand what I'm saying.

Is there an easy way to do this? Like some option in the factory-boy package?

## EDIT:

I ended up doing it the long way, passing down parameters manually. In this example, I'm showing both cases: when the parent factory has the `company` parameter(`BagTrackerFactory`) and doesn't have it but must pass it downstream (`BagFactory`).

```
class CompanyFactory(BaseFactory):
    id = get_sequence()

    class Meta:
        model = Company


class ItemFactory(BaseFactory):
    id = get_sequence()
    owner = factory.SubFactory(CompanyFactory)
    owner_id = factory.SelfAttribute("owner.id")

    class Meta:
        model = Item


class BagFactory(BaseFactory):
    id = get_sequence()
    item = factory.SubFactory(ItemFactory, owner=factory.SelfAttribute("..company"))
    item_id = factory.SelfAttribute("item.id")

    class Params:
        company = factory.SubFactory(CompanyFactory)

    class Meta:
        model = Bag


class BagTrackerFactory(BaseFactory):
    id = get_sequence()
    company = factory.SubFactory(CompanyFactory)
    company_id = factory.SelfAttribute("company.id")
    item = factory.SubFactory(ItemFactory, owner=factory.SelfAttribute("..company"))
    item_id = factory.SelfAttribute("item.id")
    bag = factory.SubFactory(BagFactory, company=factory.SelfAttribute("..company"))
    bag_id = factory.SelfAttribute("bag.id")

    class Meta:
        model = BagTracker
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, but will have to be done specifically for your codebase.

At its core, a factory has no knowledge of your models' specific structure, hence can't forward the `company` field — for instance, some models might not accept that field in their `__init__`, and providing the field would crash.

However, if you've got a chain where the field is always accepted, you may use the following pattern:

```py
class WithCompanyFactory(factory.BaseFactory):
  class Meta:
    abstract = True

  company = factory.Maybe(
    "factory_parent",  # Is there a parent factory?
    yes_declaration=factory.SelfAttribute("..company"),
    no_declaration=factory.SubFactory(CompanyFactory),
  )
```

This works thanks to the `factory_parent` attribute of the stub used when building a factory's parameters: https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#parents
This field either points to the parent (when the current factory is called as a `SubFactory`), or to `None`. With a `factory.Maybe`, we can copy the value through a `factory.SelfAttribue` when a parent is defined, and instantiate a new value.

This can be used afterwards in your code:

```py
class ItemFactory(WithCompanyFactory):
  pass

class BagFactory(WithCompanyFactory):
  item = factory.SubFactory(ItemFactory)

class BagTrackerFactory(WithCompanyFactory):
  bag = factory.SubFactory(BagFactory)


>>> tracker = BagTrackerFactory()
>>> assert tracker.company == tracker.bag.company == tracker.bag.item.company
... True

# It also works starting anywhere in the chain:
>>> company = Company(...)
>>> bag = BagFactory(company=company)
>>> assert bag.company == bag.item.company == company
... True
```

If some models must pass the `company` value to their subfactories, but without a `company` field themselves, you may also split the special `WithCompanyFactory` into two classes: `WithCompanyFieldFactory` and `CompanyPassThroughFactory`:

```py
class WithCompanyFieldFactory(factory.Factory):
  """Automatically fill this model's `company` from the parent factory."""
  class Meta:
    abstract = True

  company = factory.Maybe(
    "factory_parent",  # Is there a parent factory?
    yes_declaration=factory.SelfAttribute("..company"),
    no_declaration=factory.SubFactory(CompanyFactory),
  )


class CompanyPassThroughFactory(factory.Factory):
  """Expose the parent model's `company` field to subfactories declared in this factory."""
  class Meta:
    abstract = True

  class Params:
    company = factory.Maybe(
      "factory_parent",  # Is there a parent factory?
      yes_declaration=factory.SelfAttribute("..company"),
      no_declaration=factory.SubFactory(CompanyFactory),
    )
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution, thanks. However, it doesn't really work for my case. Sometimes there will be a parent factory, but without the `company` field. Also, to make things more difficult, sometimes the `company` attribute is sometimes called `owner`. I'm gonna stick with the custom solution and do it the long way.

Comment: Maybe this with a combination of [LazyAttribute](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#lazyattribute) ? That way you can resolve conditionals based on these different code paths